# How to commit text, annotations etc. to/from groovy-script from/to other GATE-plugin?

Tags: groovy, gate

I want to create GATE-pipeline like this:

```
... -> Plugin no.1 -> Groovy-Script -> Plugin no.2 -> ...
```

As a GATE beginner, I don't know how I can receive the document-text and its annotations from plugin no.1 to read it into my groovy-script. Then I want to edit the given document-text and/or set some more annotations with my groovy script - how can I commit this to the next plugin in the pipeline?

Edit: OK, now I see the question above isn't my problem. 
My script starts like this:

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Gate.init();
        System.out.println(doc.getContent());
    }
}
```

But when I try to load the script into GATE, I get the "Script compilation failed"-error. I don't get it, because this script

```
public class MainApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

and this script

```
Gate.init();
System.out.println(doc.getContent());
```

both work.
(I didn't tested the last one until now, that's why I thought I do a wrong call)

Comment: Are you referring to the Groovy Script PR (in the `Groovy` plugin) or do you mean you're making calls into the GATE APIs from a standalone Groovy script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [Groovy Script PR documentation](http://gate.ac.uk/userguide/sec:api:groovy:pr:bindings), there are a number of pre-defined variables available within a script that is run by the script PR:

- `doc` is the `Document` currently being processed
- `inputAS` is the `AnnotationSet` from that document corresponding to the `inputASName` runtime parameter
- `outputAS` is the `AnnotationSet` from that document corresponding to the `outputASName` runtime parameter

You can read the document content via `doc.getContent()` and modify it using [`doc.edit`](http://jenkins.gate.ac.uk/job/GATE-Nightly/javadoc/gate/Document.html#edit(java.lang.Long,%20java.lang.Long,%20gate.DocumentContent)), read annotations from previous PRs from the `inputAS` and create annotations for subsequent PRs in the `outputAS`.

Edit: I think you're mis-understanding what the Script PR expects - you should not add a class body, just a script, i.e. the script file should contain just the code that would be inside a method body without the surrounding class and method declarations.  And you should definitely *not* call `Gate.init()` in the script - your script will be called *by* GATE, once per document.  The single line:

```
println doc.getContent()
```

on its own would be a valid script for the PR, and would display the text content of each document in the Messages pane.

Comment: thank you, I already tried this but discarded it because it didn't work - like you can see in my edit above.

Comment: @Munchkin `Gate.init()` is definitely wrong, see my edit for more info.